# How much dog food should one eat? - Internal and External RestAPI & Oauth2

Tags: django, api, rest, angularjs, oauth-2.0

TL;DR - SKip down the the section marked **The Problem** though some context may be useful.

## Some background

So I have been trawling the net looking for answers to some questions I have about turning our internal API inside out and opening it up for developers to use.  Our API is already in production and is currently protected, where required, using standard sessions.

Now I'm already convinced that dog fooding your own api is a great idea so we can skip this part.  My question is very much to do with taking the internal and making it safe to be external, enter OAuth2.

On the front end we are an angular.js app spread across several sections of the site, i think its important i highlight that its not a one page app.  On the backend we have django with the rest api built using django-rest-framework.  I dont think the details of the backend are really important, but what is definitely worth noting is django renders some of these pages up.  This means that in some cases, angular is passed data up front rather than requesting everything from the api.  This also helps us make certain sections of the site more SEO friendly.  Once the page has been rendered and any initial data required has been passed to angular, everything is angular.js --> api

The last detail to mention before i actually get to the guts of the question is that the api currently has some public endpoints, content that as publicly available on the front end is by definition, publicly available from the api though this is likely something we want to change.

## Some reasoning

I have read the OAuth2 spec (almost) from start to finish several times, I have read every article i could find online, i even bought a book on the subject and there is just one part missing for me, one crucial example that would help me grok the implementation of replacing our current authentication on our web platform with OAuth.

If we are to make our API available to third parties, OAuth2 seem like the only sound choice at this time.  Dog fooding the api will only improve it.  So we are left with Needing Access tokens ourselves.  This is where I cant make a decision.

We have already started breaking the API away from the main Django api (now written in flask) so adding oauth to the api is going to be a pretty natural step.  We cant obviously give angular the keys, so what are we left with?

## The Problem

Can we replace our session based Auth with OAuth2.  Our internal api is currently Authenticated using sessions.  If we make the API available for third parties, how can we implement OAuth for the main, web platform?

*we are HTTPS by default*

- Is it safe, once a user has logged in (Resource Owner Password Flow), which would replicate the current functionality of our site very well, to use that token directly.  the token could be persisted in django and simply passed to angular js application when required.
- Would we need some kind of proxy between django and the api? this is going to double up http requests though it maybe be not so bad over a local network?
- could we handle it entirely with angular, using the implicit grant flow?  As i understand as users tokens expired, as long as the user remained logged in with the authentication server angular could asynchronously request another token to make requests with
- When a user comes to our site, the entire OAuth flow should be transparent to them.  This made client credentials seem appealing?  Is there perhaps a combination of this flow and some proxy to the api that could work, though this does seem like a bit of a security risk, allowing the website to access everything simply with client_id and client_secret?
- is this something any of the big guys do?? facebook, twitter etc?

To be honest none of the above seem like a great option.  Its gonna have a terrible impact across the board,  I can't imagine how big a pain working with those options in development would be. I mean is this even a good idea?  Is there something way simpler i have just overlooked.

The spec always hints towards solutions for cases where you have trusted first party apps like mobile clients, but honestly i just don't feel inspired with any of the stuff i have thought about for the case where the first party is actually the website.

I Appreciate anyone that has taken the time to read this.  As i mentioned, i have read everything i can find on these topics and most are based around - Should i use my own api or how can we use single sign on?  What im looking for is information on actually implementing these things in a practical sense and hopefully some pearls of wisdom for any souls that have accomplished this in production.

Thanks for taking the time to read this.

Answer (score 0):

I have been thinking about this for awhile - I'm currently working to build an angular application that accesses a REST API built in node. In keeping with REST, I shouldn't be maintaining a session, and instead should be passing some user/password detail along with each request.

Now obviously, a lot of API's are happy to stick with some sort of basic authorization or api keys thereby avoid oauth2, but I wanted to log on with google/facebook, so a certain amount of token wrangling was going to be required. The particular flow I'm using is this -

1. User accesses the angular application. As they are not logged in, they will be given a log in page with a choice to login with google/facebook.
2. Assuming they click to log on with google - the link sends a request to my node server, with starts the google authorization flow by redirecting the user to googles sign in page.
3. They give access to the app/log in - which then redirects back to the node server, which acquires the oauth2 token from google. The node servers then stores this token for the particular user.
4. Finally the node server redirects back to the angular app along with the token in the header. This token is stored the browser session, and is used when the app makes an api request. If the api request receives a valid token it responds in kind, otherwise it passes an error and the angular app notes this and redirects to the login page with some sort of relevant error notice.

If you're opening the API up to third parties, you will probably need to do a bit more work, but it is not something I have considered too much at the moment.